# Spinner still empty

Tags: android, spinner

i was create a spinner base on an BaseAdapter

but when i select a value still always empty

it's my code

**SpinnerAdapter.class**

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<School> schools;
    private Activity parentActivity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public SpinnerAdapter(Activity parent, List<School> l) {
        parentActivity = parent;
        schools = l;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) parentActivity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return schools.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return schools.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_spinner, null);

        TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
        TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.libelle);
        School myObj = schools.get(position);
        text1.setText(String.valueOf(myObj.get_id()));
        text2.setText(myObj.get_nom());
        text1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        return view;
    }
}
```

School.class

```
public class School {

    private int _id;
    private String _nom;


    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(int _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String get_nom() {
        return _nom;
    }

    public void set_nom(String _nom) {
        this._nom = _nom;
    }
}



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/libelle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

i was create a request using volley library to get data from json file

this my result

[image]

but when i select a value style alwsays empty like this

[image]

thanks for your help

Comment: Could you show row_spinner.xml?

Comment: i was add code of spinner row in the post thanks for your answer

Comment: Could you add some more code from where you use the adapter and inflate the spinner? Did you overwrite some onClickListener or so, that might intercept the event from the spinner dialog?

Comment: Maybe you can try to use this layout android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, because your layout is not very complicated, no need to define by yourself, Android already provide some basic layouts for this kind simple view, then you can avoid a lot of problems and save more time to do the core logic.

Comment: thanx i wana try now